Unitary Operator and it relation to Hamiltonian
I read in a book that one can write Hamiltonian as
$$H_k = e^{-i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} H e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}},$$
where $H$ is Hamiltonian, i.e.
$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V.$$
How can one justify the first equation? Is $H_k$ related by some unitary transformation to $H$ giving rise to this equation, and how can one prove the equivalence of this equation?

Could you give us a bit of context? In which book did you read it?

@AFG Its from David Vanderbilt Berry phases in electronic structure theory (Chapter -2)

He is just defining a $\mathbf{k}$-dependent effective Hamiltonian, justified for convenience.

So you are saying he has just defined it like this, and there is no physical or mathematical interpretation behind it! @AFG

Certainly there are physical and mathematical interpretations / reasons for defining $H_k$ this way. But, it is at the same time also just a definition.

@JakobKS Can you tell me more about it!

@Mt I wrote an answer now :)

When the potential $V$ is periodic with some period $R$, Bloch's theorem says that the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian can be written in the form $\psi_{nk}(r) = u_{nk}(r) e^{ikr}$, where $u_{nk}$ is periodic with the same periodicity as $V$, i.e. $u_{nk}(r+R) = u_{nk}(r)$ for all $r$.
To find the eigenstates of the system, one needs to solve the Schrödinger equation
$$H \psi_{nk}(r) = E_{nk} \psi_{nk}(r),$$
which in terms of the periodic part $u_{nk}$ for a given $k$ becomes
$$H u_{nk}(r) e^{ikr} = E_{nk} u_{nk}(r) e^{ikr},$$
or
$$ H_k u_{nk} = E_{nk} u_{nk},$$
where $H_k = e^{-ikr} H e^{ikr}$.
Defining $H$ in this way therefore allows you to express the Schrödinger equation in terms of $u$ rather than $\psi$. This is convenient because it allows you to utilize the periodicity of the system, and allows you to solve the eigenvalue problem for just one value of $k$ at a time.
